# ASP.NET Membership for one website but multiple and potentially unknown sql server instance

Tags: asp.net-membership

This my problem. I have 1 and only 1 website for multiple customer. To access to their data, customers use urls like this : 
http://customer1.mysite.com
http://customer2.mysite.com
etc

Each customer have a SqlServer instance with their data.

Depends to the URL the website connect to the right sql server instance. This is good.

My issue is about Membership, each instance have is own "membership database". In my webconfig I configure a dummy section like this  :

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="MyMembershipProvider"
type="MapApp.MyMembershipProvider, MyApp"            
enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
enablePasswordReset="true" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
applicationName="/" 
requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
minRequiredPasswordLength="5" 
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" 
connectionStringName="A_DATABASE" />
</providers>           
</membership>
```

Also I have a custom Membershipprovider with code like this :

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider   
{   
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)   
{   
    base.Initialize(name, config);   
    // Update the private connection string field in the base class.   
    string connectionString = "my new connection string depdend of the customer"  
    // Set private property of Membership provider.   
    FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);   
                     connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);   
}   
}
```

but is not enough a have some issues like "already instanciate" when I call my custom membership provider.

Someone can help me ? Please...

Sorry for my bad english in this long post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the solution but it's a bit strange.

In my customMemberShipProvider class I must have an empty constructor even if I never call it. And I need another constructor (with args even if I never use it).

So this is my code :

```
public class myMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public myMembershipProvider()
    {
        //never use
    }

    public myMembershipProvider(string dummyArg)
    {
        string configPath = "~/web.config";
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);
        MembershipSection section = (MembershipSection)config.GetSection("system.web/membership");
        ProviderSettingsCollection settings = section.Providers;
        NameValueCollection membershipParams = settings[section.DefaultProvider].Parameters;
        if ((HttpContext.Current.Session != null) && (HttpContext.Current.Session["SubDomainInstanceName"] != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session["SubDomainInstanceName"].ToString())))
        {
            membershipParams.Add("Instance", HttpContext.Current.Session["SubDomainInstanceName"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            membershipParams.Add("Instance", "default");
        }
        Initialize(section.DefaultProvider, membershipParams);
    }


    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        //need to remove the key before call Initialize method 
        string instance = config["Instance"];
        config.Remove("Instance");
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        // Update the private connection string field in the base class.   
        string connectionString = //my specific connectionstring;
        // Set private property of Membership provider.   
        FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Seems like you are attempting to use a different connection string for the database, based on the URL. This might be a bit less elegant, but how about getting the code for the sql membership provider and modifying it so that the connection string which it uses is based on the users URL. I think this could be a good work around if you are truly only using one asp.net application.